# Wordpress Attachment Category Bulk Edit

Tags: php, wordpress, edit, attachment, bulk

I added a custom taxonomy called 'attachment_cat' to attachments and am trying to add the possibility to bulk assign this taxonomy (like in posts, pages or custom post types).

I would prefer a solution without a plugin as I assume there exists an easy solution using for example a filter.

Comment: Why not to use any plugin. ?

Comment: Because I'm interested in how you can do this :) (I wasn't able to find a hook for this problem)

Comment: See if this works for you.... 

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112078/bulk-term-assignment-for-attachment-taxonomies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why I asked you about the plugin . Here it is , this plugin gives you the bulk edit option for media files.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-assistant/

Comment: Thank you :) Actually i prefere the plugin from your first link, because it doesn't add too many features and it is quite small ^^

Comment: I also wanted to refer you to the plugin first .. :)